# Validate Excel cell format

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

i want validate my cell on basis in below values

For ex :

1. 12345678 Test Test Tets so beginning of cell always with 8 numeric digits
2. Test Test Tets (12345678) end of cell always with 8 numeric digits inside brackets

Trying below but it only give the first character numeric or not

```
=IF(ISERR(LEFT(A2,1)*1),"letter","number")
```

[image]

Comment: ISNUMBER(LEFT(A2,8)) will return True if and only if the left hand 8 digits of A2 is a valid number. 
If there are only two possible cases, this is all you need - all others must be "not number". 
If you need to explicitly test for 8 digits in brackets as well, because there is a third group of cases which could be neither, you might need to edit your post to make it a bit clearer.

Comment: added image of required output hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(LEFT(A2,8)),"Number",IF(ISNUMBER(MID(A2,LEN(A2)-9,8)),"Letter","Neither"))
```